# Responsive design on Safari media queries issue

Tags: css, safari, media-queries

I got a problem with website.
It's a jquery mobile framework, and the responsive design works well in Chrome and Firefox, but it does not in Safari on the mobile view.
i inspect it and looks like thet the media queries bellow 600px doesnt work.
Could you give me any help?
i wanna try whit some hacks but i dont know how to use it in media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){ 
.mi-slider {
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}

.mi-slider ul {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    bottom: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
*/much more styles*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answer my own question, but i could fixed it, was easy, just making a new .css for hacks:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/webkit.css" media="screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)" type="text/css" />
```

and there put the media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
#text_biblioteca {
    margin-left:24.553954%;
}
#image2_biblioteca {
    margin-left:24.165918%
}
#box2_biblioteca {
    margin-left:7.57416%
}
}
```

and done!!!